# VB.net Windows 10 Universal App - Combine Images

Tags: vb.net, image, windows-10, win-universal-app

I am trying to combine 4 images into 1 in a Windows 10 Universal App so that each of the 4 images is a quadrant of the 1 final image.  I've researched and found ways to do this but they don't seem to be available on Windows 10 Universal App, such as using the "Graphics" class or using the "WriteableBitmap.Render" method.  I am using Writeable Bitmaps in my app and through finding some code and modifying it, I can scale down an image from an existing file.  I am just at a loss how to combine the 4 scaled images into 1 larger image.
For the code I have that is working this is the function in VB.NET that works:

```
Private Async Function GetScaledWritableBitmapFromStream(ByVal inStream As Stream, ByVal inDesiredWidth As Int32, inDesiredHeight As Int32) As Task(Of WriteableBitmap)

    Dim decoder As BitmapDecoder = Await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(inStream.AsRandomAccessStream())
    Dim tempScaleFactorX As Double = inDesiredWidth / decoder.PixelWidth
    Dim tempScaleFactorY As Double = inDesiredHeight / decoder.PixelHeight
    Dim tempScaleFactor As Double
    If tempScaleFactorX > tempScaleFactorY Then
        tempScaleFactor = tempScaleFactorX
    Else
        tempScaleFactor = tempScaleFactorY
    End If

    Dim tempBitmapTransform As New BitmapTransform
    tempBitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = decoder.PixelWidth * tempScaleFactor
    tempBitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = decoder.PixelHeight * tempScaleFactor
    Dim pixelData As PixelDataProvider = Await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, tempBitmapTransform, ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation, ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage)

    Dim pixels As Byte() = pixelData.DetachPixelData()
    Dim bmp As WriteableBitmap = New WriteableBitmap(Convert.ToInt32(decoder.PixelWidth * tempScaleFactor), Convert.ToInt32(decoder.PixelHeight * tempScaleFactor))

    Using bmpStream As Stream = bmp.PixelBuffer.AsStream()
        bmpStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        Await bmpStream.WriteAsync(pixels, 0, Convert.ToInt32(bmpStream.Length))

    End Using

    Return bmp

End Function
```

And this code is called from the following routine:

```
file = Await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(_ListOfPicsToShow.Item(1))

        If file IsNot Nothing Then
            Using FileStream As Stream = Await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync()
                Dim writeableBmp = Await GetScaledWritableBitmapFromStream(FileStream, tempWidth / 2, tempHeight / 2)
                imageMain.Stretch = Stretch.None
                imageMain.Source = writeableBmp  
            End Using
        End If
```

_ListOfPicsToShow is a list of file names and paths of images.

Any guidance would be appreciated.  imageMain is a Xaml "Image" control that will display the combined image.  Right now it works to display the scaled image.

Comment: I'll add this as a comment because I'm not that known with the vb.net code. There is a great library available on Nuget called WriteableBitmapEx and it has a method called Blit that can be used to 'stitch' up several images in one WriteableBitmap. And that WriteableBitmap can be used as your source. I have c# example here http://depblog.weblogs.us/2012/06/22/comdaybe-image-manipulation-in-windows-8-metro-app/

Comment: It can be done with [RenderTargetBitmap class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)